# Why using .last() on distincted queryset gives me object with was not primary in queryest?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm

`Bid.objects.all()` gives me two columns with date and bid_value. I want to have only one bid per date. Bid should be the highes value. So `Bid.objects.all().order_by("date","bid_value").distinct("date")` gives me proper order.

But using last not only takes last row from QuerySet, but it takes last element from group_by made from distinct which i dont want. I would want only last element of queryset without any order changes.

[image: Before distinct] [image: After distinct]
[image: .last()]
[image: .first()]

1.`Bid.objects.all()`

2.`Bid.objects.all().order_by("date","bid").distinct("date")`

3.`Bid.objects.all().order_by("date","bid").distinct("date").last()`

but it should give me 15.11.2022/50zł and actually

`list(Bid.objects.all().order_by("date","bid").distinct("date").last())[-1]`

gives me proper object

4.`Bid.objects.all().order_by("date","bid").distinct("date").first()`

How i can still use .last() / .first() - without taking it into list. Because when i use list(Queryset), i have proper values on last objects. But changing queryset to list is not good standard i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a GROUP BY clause.

In Plain SQL you would write something like

```
SELECT bid_date, MAX(bid) 
FROM bids
GROUP BY bid_date 
ORDER BY bid_count DESC;
```

In Django you could use [aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/) or [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), but aggregate clauses are terminal whereas if you use annotations, it will return a QuerySet on which you can use the `first()` and `last()` calls.

```
Bid.objects \
.values('bid_date') \
.annotate(Max('bid_count')) \
.order_by('bid_count__max') \
.last()
```

**This is a helpful article on group by queries in Django: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html**

Comment: Yeah it throws now dict and first/last works properly. Maybe do you know what to do if i have more attributes for bid object? Like who made it, etc. Now it only shows bid_date and max_bid.

But .values('bid_date',...'bid_owner') makes group by not distinctable only by date. And .last().bid_owner does not have bid owner with normal query...